# Is there a way to check token count i have voted?

Tags: tokens

My account shows 10 eos as balance, and shows 90 eos as staked for bandwidth.
If i vote with this account, how many tokens gonna to be voted actually?

Comment: This is poorly written, please edit the question and make it more clear what you're asking.

Comment: sorry for my poor english. I gonna try to refine it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking a cleos way, just use `cleos get account YOUR_ACCOUNT`.

```
bob@bob-VirtualBox:~/eos/build/programs/nodeos$ cleos -u http://mainnet.genereos.io get account gqztkmjsguge
permissions: 
     owner     1:    1 EOS6HPhh7LyHeir268VLphF52R7ytjtLMAWSCV5QYPYS4gruJHzuS
        active     1:    1 EOS6HPhh7LyHeir268VLphF52R7ytjtLMAWSCV5QYPYS4gruJHzuS
memory: 
     quota:     7.953 KiB    used:     7.396 KiB  

net bandwidth: 
     staked:         55.5000 EOS           (total stake delegated from account to self)
     delegated:       0.0000 EOS           (total staked delegated to account from others)
     used:              2.61 KiB  
     available:        19.27 MiB  
     limit:            19.27 MiB  

cpu bandwidth:
     staked:         55.5000 EOS           (total stake delegated from account to self)
     delegated:       0.0000 EOS           (total staked delegated to account from others)
     used:             52.26 ms   
     available:        3.802 sec  
     limit:            3.854 sec  

producers:
     eoscannonchn    eoslaomaocom    helloeoscnbp    
     oraclegogogo
```